# Matplotlib gives error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am running the sample code given here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.py
on my machine and getting an error saying "pie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'center' "
My python version is 2.7.10 32 bits. I have installed numpy,scipy and matplotlib.
I am using numpy and scipy from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib while matplotlib was installed using pip install command directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your matplotlib version? (best way to find is to print `matplotlib.__version__` in python REPL/prompt)

`center=(,)` argument is introduced in 1.5 (dev version, not stable yet).

See this: http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie

The most recent stable versions (1.4.3 / 1.4.2) do not support this argument.

EDIT: As far as I know, matplotlib 1.5 is not currently available via pip. You'll have to check it out from git (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git) and build it on your own.

Comment: print matplotlib.version did not work instead I used print matplotlib.__version__. The version is 1.4.3 so that's the reason.

Comment: 1.5 is not on pip because it is not released yet ;)  There will be an RC 'soon', just a few blocking issues left.